# c++ including eigen in my makefile

Tags: c++, include, makefile, eigen

This seems to be the correct answer to my problem, however I think it's more the way I am writing my makefile as I already have the steps described in the link below (I know how to build things).

[How to write a makefile for a C++ project which uses Eigen, the C++ template library for linear algebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280738/how-to-write-a-makefile-for-a-c-project-which-uses-eigen-the-c-template-lib/3280845#3280845)

### Error:

```
SASAGeometry.h:6:22: error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory 
SASAGeometry.h:7:20: error: Eigen/LU: No such file or directory
```

The problematic lines in my header file are simply :

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/LU>
```

So here is the makefile (am on overkill in the INCLUDE line, I know):

```
CC = g++
BIN = .

INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include/eigen2/ -I. -I/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/ -I/home/mark/Applications/eigen/Eigen/src/ -I /usr/local/include

CFLAGS = -pipe

LFLAGS = -lm

GeomTest_OBJS = geomTest.o SASAGeometry.o

geomTest_source = SASAGeometry.cpp SASAGeometry.h sasa_transformMatrix.cpp sasa_transformMatrix.h geomSetup.cpp


geomTest    : $(GeomTest_OBJS) makefile
            $(CC) -o geomTest.o -o SASAGeometry.o $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(geomTest_source) $(LFLAGS)
            $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/geomTest geomTest.o SASAGeometry.o $(LFLAGS)

clean       : \rm *.o *~ p1
```

any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What’s the error? Also,  this part of the flags is almost certainly useless: `-I/usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/` (probably also the one including `src`). Finally, setting `CC` to `g++` is just vile. Use `CXX` (and `CXXFLAGS`) instead.

Comment: I know its useless, I put in as much as I could to point the compiler to the Eigen header files (and yeah, I put two versions of it on my machine. Just for this and just in case.) As for the CXX things, surely I can call my makefile vars whatever I like? Put the errors in my post now *embarass*.

Comment: I did change the make file as you suggested though, just for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note, read comments to get gist of the final solution.  I will update the answer when I have clarification from the original poster of the question.)

Sometimes it is the obvious, which is easy to miss.  Please check that your user has read permissions for all files and directories in /usr/local/include/eigen2 and /usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen.  Also double check the files you are including actually exist in /usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen.

Additional:
It sounds like the install was deployed directly into /usr/include/eigen2 and NOT /usr/include/Eigen like the documentation assumes.  That means the header files the tutorials want are in /usr/include/eigen2.  Your -I needs to point to `/usr/include/` (I think thats by default in GNU GCC). Your source code is incorrect, it should be  `#include <eigen2/Core>` and `#include <eigen2/LU>`.  Whoever installed eigen on your system changed the name of the root directory specified in the documentations.

Comment: I got very excited when I read this as I often have these sort of mental blocks (spent a day trying to get ruby to call some bash scripts (haha) that I forgot to make executable...), but no, all have read permissions (ls -o /path/to/headers told me so). (I even sudo'd make, just in case). HOWEVER. The files don't exist in /usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen they exist in /usr/local/include/eigen2/Eigen/src (which I also included in the makefile to no avail.)

Comment: OK, I think I know the issue then, I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This is a real puzzler for me. (And I'm working with eigen2 still I am afraid.)

Comment: SASAGeometry.h:6:23: error: eigen2/Core: No such file or directory
SASAGeometry.h:7:21: error: eigen2/LU: No such file or directory. I am glad this is not just me. Thanks for the help James!

Comment: hahaha the headers were in .../eigen2/Eigen/ that's a big #include, thanks for nudging me right at the answer AND leaving me work to do, it's the best thing! If I could boost you I would.

Comment: @James, what you write is *not true*. Eigen does install files under e.g. `/usr/local/include/eigen3` (this should be specified with `-I`), and then #include `Eigen/Core` in the source, which really is file `/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core`. This is to make it possible to switch eigen version just by changing `-I`, and to have both versions installed at once.

Comment: @eudoxos, That is what I thought, especially after mordidslug's reply that the headers were in `.../eigen2/Eigen` but he says he got the includes working with the full path and not his -I option which should have had the same affect.  I still don't know the exact answer that got him up and running or I would update my response.. but it was enough to lead him to a solution.

Comment: @James: I suggest you edit your answer, since it is misleading and only corrected in comments which don't get as much attention.

Comment: @morbidslug, What was your final solution so I can revise the answer to be more correct and helpful for others.  Did you remove any of the -I's?  Did you change the `#include` lines in your source?

Answer (score 1):

The question you link to has the correct answer. You just need to use the proper `-I` flag to point to the Eigen headers. You should only need one `-I` for all of the Eigen headers.

Comment: So, all I need to do is find the eigen headers with, say, 'find / -wholename \*Eigen/*/*.h', look at the result, find the relevant header files to include write the line -I/path/to/eigen2/ and just simply build the code with 'make geomTest'?